# Check if a number x is positive (x>0) by ONLY using bitwise operators in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

`isPositive` - return `true` if `x > 0`, otherwise `false`

Example: `isPositive(-1)`

Legal ops: `!` `~` `&` `^` `|` `+` `<<` `>>`

Max ops: `8`

Note: No conditional statements are allowed.

```
inline bool isPositive(int32_t x) {
  return ???;
}
```

Comment: Positive numbers are greater than zero; non-negative numbers include zero.  Try a Google search 'define:positive' (one entry is: greater than zero; "positive numbers").

Comment: @Konrad, well, 0 isn't positive. It seems proper.

Comment: yeah , it is not the usual definition of +'ve , but this was asked.

Comment: Do they really ask such questions in interview?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
return !((x & 0x80000000) >> 31 | !x);
```

Comment: `x & 0x80000000` discards all bits except the highest, yeilding only the signage bit, however the `>> 31` makes this superflous on any system that guarentees bits on the MSB side to be zero when right shifting

Comment: you can use (1 << 31) instead of 0x80000000

Comment: I included the `& 0x8000000` because I thought it made it easier to understand. (i.e., Shifting only highest bit over.) But you could write it as `!(x >> 31 | !x);`.

Comment: +1 to Necrolis, it will fail on my pentium, but the question says int is 4 bytes...

Comment: Also - no need for the `>> 31` operation.

Comment: Better to use `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT` to determine the number of bits in an int and then use the correct mask and shift values.

Comment: @Michael, the constraint was only bitwise operators, so you need to put the 0x80000000 bit in the same position as the result of !x which is either 0 or 1. You need to shift one or the other....

Comment: If your computer uses 1's compliment then this will return true for -0 (do you want that)?

Comment: you don't need to shift, just `!(x & 0x80000000) && !x` is enough

Answer (score 19):

```
int isPositive(int x) {
   return !((x&(1<<31)) | !x);
}
```

`x&(1<<31` is to check if the number is negative.

`!x` is to check if the number is zero.

A number is positive if it's not negative and not zero.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this fails for 0.

Comment: @JoshD: That's what the requirement says.

Comment: @codaddict, he says return 1 for x > 0. So doesn't that mean return 0 for x == 0? Zero is not positive.

Comment: @codaddict - Should return 1 only if number is > 0.

Comment: I thought `&&` wasn’t a valid operation.

Comment: @codaddict - && cannot be used as it is not one of legal operators mentioned

Answer (score 10):

```
int isPositive(int x)
{
 return (!(x & 0x80000000) & !!x); 
}
```

Comment: Almost, you need to shift this right 31 bits to get 1 rather than 0x80000000

Comment: @JoshD: the result of ! is a bool which is mapped to 0 or 1.

Comment: ooh, good call. This makes much of my code (and of the considerations for different platforms) completely redundant.

Comment: nuts. In his last question there was no !, I scalded my brain ... sorry for the invalid comment.

Comment: @JoshD - yeah , the previous question had no !. If we could substitute other operators for it m then the solution might be easy .

Answer (score 3):

Let's play with the sign bit: `sign(~n)` : 1 if n >= 0

To get rid of the case when `n` is 0: `sign(~n + 1)` : 1 if n > 0 or n = MIN_INT

So, we want the case when both functions return 1:

```
return ((~n & (~n + 1)) >> 31) & 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `XOR (^)`?

Try this,

```
{
    return ((x>>31)&1)^(!!x); 
}
```

It can deal with the 0 case well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a two’s complement representation (not always the case!), this can be achieved by testing whether the most significant bit is set (in which case the number is negative).

Notice that the following code uses illegal operations (`+`, `*` and `-`) but these are for clarity and platform independence only. If you know more about your particular platform, e.g. that `int` is a 32 bit number, the relevant constants can be replaced by their numeric value.

```
// Will be 1 iff x < 0.
int is_neg = (x & (INT_MAX + 1)) >> (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) - 1);
// Will be 1 iff x != 0.
int is_not_zero = !!x;
return !is_neg & is_not_zero;
```

Answer (score 0):

if your working with a number system that uses the MSB as the signage bit, you can do:

```
int IsPositive(int x)
{
    return (((x >> 31) & 1) ^ 1) ^ !x;
}
```

Comment: seeing as there is no state for 0(ie: 0 is meant to be neither) its easier to have zero be treated as positive(imo), but it can be ammend to have it as negative(if needed)

Comment: Zero is not positive. The question is quite clear, return 1 if x > 0 return 0 otherwise. This does not do that.

Comment: You need to add a `^!x` to handle the case where the parameter is 0:  `return (((x >> 31) & 1) ^ 1) ^ !x;`.  Note that even though the `!` operator isn't really a bitwise operator, it's in the question's permitted operations.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done assembler for quite a while, but as far as I remember first digit in the word represents negative value e.g. 1000 is -8, hence if most significant bit is 1 the number is negative. So the answer is `!(x>>31)`

Answer (score 0):

You have another option here:

```
int is_positive = (0&x^((0^x)&-(0<x)));
```

It is just a (0 & min(0,x)).

Test [here](http://goo.gl/w1cLWH)

Answer (score -1):

int isPositive(int x)

{

```
 return ( ! (x & ( 1 << 31 ) ) );
```

}

It will return 1 if given no is +ve and return 0 if given no is -ve

in this function we got sign bit if that is 1 it means no is -ve so we return 0
and if sign bit is 0 it means number is +ve so we return 1 .

Comment: This function only gives correct values if value of x is greater than zero or less than zero.  It does not give the required value of 0 if the value of x is zero.  It will instead return a 1 when it is supposed to return a 1 only when the value of x is greater than zero.  If value of x is less than one, meaning zero or a negative number, then the function is supposed to return a zero.

Answer (score -1):

```
int x,len;
x = 0x0fffffff;
len = (sizeof(x) * 8) - 2;

if ((x>>len))
 printf("Negative\n");
else
 printf("Positive\n");
```

X will be either int or char(Integral type).

Answer (score -2):

return !((x >> 31) & 1);
This is to check MSB.