# How do I find whether a number is positive, negative or zero without using if or for?

Tags: c, function, boolean, logic

I want to implement the sign and zero flag setting in microprocessor. So I need to write a function to find whether the number is positive, negative or zero without using `if` or `for` loops and also **only Boolean and bitwise operators are allowed**. I did the following. But how to I implement it for `zero` condition ?

```
int status (int x) {
    int sign = (x >> 31);
    return sign;
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Give me three output values for each condition...

Comment: @rajraj `status(5) = 1, status(-5) = -1, status(0) = 0`

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912375/check-if-a-number-x-is-positive-x0-by-only-using-bitwise-operators-in-c

Comment: @jogojapan that was for bitwise operator.

Comment: @Navnath What do you mean?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan you can use shift operators....

Comment: @jogojapan...I know this Q. is similar to your suggestion, but he want to use only boolean operator.

Comment: @Navnath The question says boolean _and_ bitwise operators are allowed, or am I reading this wrongly?

Comment: @noufal ok although I love devnull answer, but let me think using bitwise op

Comment: @jogojapan yeah ... you are right...

Comment: @jogojapan.. Your right, he change Q. before few minute..

Comment: a book called "hacker's delight",has a lot of example about these trick including yours.

Comment: @noufal... Check my answer does it work for you ?

Comment: I got it, It was quite simple


It can be easly done by

`return ((!!x) | (x >> 31));`

Answer (score 7):

The following will return `-1` for negative values, `0` for zero, `1` for positive values of `x`.

```
int status (int x) {
  int sign = (x > 0) - (x < 0); 
  return sign;
}
```

Comment: + nice suggestion, but OP need via Boolean, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: devnull I can't use `greater than (>)` or `less than (<)` operators..

Answer (score 2):

Is this enough for your purpose?

```
int status(int val)
{
    int minus = (val&0x80000000)&&TRUE;
    int pos = (val&0x7FFFFFFF)&&(!(val&0x80000000));
    int r = 0 - minus + pos;
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int status (unsigned no) {
  int sign = 0;

   // If Zero             // If -Ve = -1 OR If +Ve = -2
   (sign = ( no | 0 )) && ( sign = (~( ( (no << 1) >> 1 ) == no)) );

   // If +Ve
   (sign == -2) && (sign = 1);

  return sign;
}
```

Comment: I got it, It was quite simple


It can be easly done by

`return ((!!x) | (x >> 31));`

Comment: @noufal...Yes your code is working correct but it is not portable. It will only work for 32 bit.

Comment: @Navanth yes... that's correct.. but here its ok for me.. do you know how to do otherwise ?

Comment: @noufal...You can use `sizeof` operator as ->  `return ((!!x) | (x >> (sizeof(int)*8) - 1));` but you need to compile for respective platform to get correct result.