# Count number of positive numbers

Tags: java

I have an array of natural numbers A. i.e. `A[i] >=0`
I need to count the number of positives without any comparison
How can it be implemented?

Comment: what counts as a comparison?
`(n & 0x80000000)` checks whether the leftmost bit is set, which is the sign bit in two's complement.
If this bit is set, it is negative.

Comment: a simple solution will be to find the square root of the number and if the result is posiible it will be a positive int or if it throws the exception its a negative int (surely there is no square root of a negative number).

Comment: Why do you need to do it without any comparison?  What does it mean to do it without comparison?  Is it OK if you call a library function that compares but your code does not?

Comment: @Raildex - there are no negative numbers in array

Comment: @YeshwinVermaTheProgrammer - array doesn`t have negative numbers

Comment: @tech if the array does not contain negatives, why do you want the number of positives? Just take the array length and you have it.

Comment: @Raildex probably because zero is not positive number?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `java.lang.Math` `signum()` function which returns *signum function* of method argument, i.e. returns zero if an argument is zero, *1.0* if an argument is greater than zero and *-1.0* if the argument is less than zero.

```java
static boolean isPositive(int N)
{
    return Math.signum(N) == 1;
}
```

```
System.out.println(isPositive(0)); // false
System.out.println(isPositive(1)); // true
System.out.println(isPositive(5)); // true
```

Comment: I'm not sure this can be counted as a solution because you compare the result of `signum` call to 1, its the old comparison in disguise :)

Comment: If `==` is counted as a comparison then the bit-masking approach (your suggestion) is also not acceptable. But it can be easily avoided by using an array of size 2 and incrementing arr[Math.signum(N)] for every integer in the array. The count of positive numbers would be = `arr[ 1 ]`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume its an interview question or something, or maybe some sort of learning exercise. So no "in-depth" knowledge of Java APIs is required.
I also assume that you can't use any "if" conditions.

One fairly "dumb" way to do this (technically answers the question, but its so dump that I'm posting it for fun really) so ***Don't use it in any "real" code***:

```
        int numOfPositives = 0;
        int[] array = {0, 5, 7, 0, 4, 0, 9, 8};
        for (int elem : array) {
            try {
                int test = 1 / elem;
                numOfPositives++;
            } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
                // nah, this is 0, won't count it
            }
        }
        System.out.println(numOfPositives);
```

No comparisons :)

More serious answer probably would include the bit shifting that lets you implementing the "isPositive" method.

I've found [this answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912375/check-if-a-number-x-is-positive-x0-by-only-using-bitwise-operators-in-c), so no need to duplicate I guess.

Comment: what if the test variable is 1/-5 then also we will count it as positive number?

Comment: In the question  appears that "I have an array of natural numbers A. i.e. A[i] >=0" so I assume that this condition holds for each element of the array". Certainly natural numbers can't be negative. Well, technically "natural" numbers do not include zero as well so I really assumed its a small mistake (otherwise the question doesn't make sense).

Comment: Yeah, but a simple solution with  negative numbers will be to find the square root of the number and if the result is posiible it will be a positive int or if it throws the exception its a negative int (surely there is no square root of a negative number).

Comment: In Math, yes, its a complex number, in Java however you can write `System.out.println(Math.sqrt(-3))` you will get NaN and not an exception. In any way, as I said, my basic assumption was that there are no negative numbers. I've also emphasized that this solution was more "for fun" than for the real work. So even if you could come up with sqrt based solution (feel free to post it really) - it will be more or less equally bad as mine :) Again, the correct way of answering this type of questions is using bit masking as I've mentioned in the last sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solution works for you with comparision.

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class CountPositiveNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer arr[] = { -1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, -2, 4, -100, null };

        long positiveNumberCount = Stream.of(arr).filter(num -> (Objects.nonNull(num) && num > 0))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream().count();

        System.out.println("Positive Numbers Count ==> " + positiveNumberCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: `num > 0` is a comparison that OP wants to avoid

Answer (score 0):

Using library methods:

```
int count(int[] input) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(input).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    list.removeAll(Collections.singletonList(0));
    return list.size();
}
```

```
System.out.println(count(new int[]{0, 5, 7, 0, 4, 0, 9, 8}));
```

> 5

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solution works without comparision.

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class CountPositiveNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer arr[] = { -1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, -2, 4, -100, null };
        String[] responses = {"Negative", "Zero", "Positive"};

        long positiveNumberCount = Stream.of(arr)
                .filter(num -> (Objects.nonNull(num) && "Positive".equals(responses[1 + (num >> 31) - (-num >> 31)])))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream().count();

        System.out.println("Positive Numbers Count ==> " + positiveNumberCount);
    }
}
```